# creating stiching object causes error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching

I'm tring to use the opencv stitching modul in QT.
After calling the factory method:

```
Stitching sticher = Sticher::createDefault();
```

The programm collapse and i get the return value -1073741515

I used other opencv modules before without any problems and I don't know what the value means and what I'm doing wrong:

```
#include <opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Stitcher stich= Stitcher::createDefault();

    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see I created a new projekt with nothing in it.
In the Stitcher class I see:

```
static Stitcher createDefault(bool try_use_gpu=false)
```

I tried also:

```
Stitcher stich= Stitcher::createDefault(false);
Stitcher stich= Stitcher::createDefault(true);
```

and

```
bool value=false or true;
    Stitcher stich= Stitcher::createDefault(value);
```

the return value stays the same.
Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong or what the return value means.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

even though all other opencv modules worked fine for me using x64 compiler
I tryed to link against x86 and use an older compiler version.
Now it seems to work fine for me. 
The exact reason stays dubious for me, but maybe even this infomation help someone.